# Load search results from external domain and embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I want do load search results from one gaming website and embed into my web page. Search page have own url structure, and items are showing in `<li>` tags. 
I tried this:

```
<ol id="ig-panel-center"></ol>
<script>
$( "#ig-panel-center" ).load( "https://www.instant-gaming.com/en/search/?all_types=1&min_price=0&max_price=100&noprice=1&min_discount=0&max_discount=100&min_reviewsavg=10&max_reviewsavg=100&noreviews=1&available_in=RS&gametype=all&all_cats=1&sort_by=discount_asc .ig-search-items li" );
</script>
```

But nothing load on my web page.

So, I do not want classic iframe embeding, I want to "grab" results and show on my website. I want to make my own html struture and styling (like widget or similar).

[image: Like this]

[image: Not like this]

Comment: you don't have access to that page because of CORS

Comment: Any suggestion how to make this?

Comment: you can't you don't have access to that page, is www.instant-gaming.com your page ?

Comment: No. So, only with php?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to or can request changes from the "external site", you can create or request a jsonp or similar (a javascript with the values you need)
Then you could embed that as a normal javascript and use the values.

Otherwise your best bet is to do a server side request, and parse the result, so you can display it.

(It could be a seperate page, so you actually make an ajax request, to a page on your server, that does the request to the server - then you could also cache and pre-load this, as performance will suff some this way)